# How can I fix my navbar being stuck partway down the screen?

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a website and have a navbar, set to be sticky using CSS. However, when I scroll down the navbar seems to be "stuck" a little bit down (you can see this in the second picture). Can anyone help me with this?

Here's the code that I used to make the navbar sticky.

```
.header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
}

.content {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 1040;
}
```

[website navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMweL.png)

[the same navbar, scrolled halfway down the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFlkF.png)

Comment: Looks like standard `position:fixed;` to me.  Is your issue that the text is showing from behind the nav bar?

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. How can I fix it so the text won't show behind the navbar?

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link to the site that needs fixing — otherwise, this question will lose any value to future visitors once the problem is solved or if the site you're linking to is inaccessible. Posting a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example (MCVE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Comment: Your nav bar doesn't go all the way across because of `width:98%;` nor all the way to the top.  Either make it go all the way across and stuck at the very top `top:0;` or, if you don't want the red to go all the way across the wrap it in a div which is white but does go all the way across.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see what you are trying to say. Fixed positioning means that the `.header-wrapper` will be "floating" above all of your other html content. So what you are seeing is not that it's stuck. It just means that it's fixed to the top of the page like it should be. Try removing the padding and margin from , so that you don't see the text scrolling out from the top of the header, like so:

```css
body {margin:0;padding:0}

.header-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 10;
  background-color:blue;
}

.content {
  padding-top:20px;
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  width: 1040;
}
```

```html
<header class="header-wrapper">
  Header
</header>
<main class="content">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam, natus sed, nisi ratione, delectus sequi ullam consequuntur neque quas veritatis fugit dolore inventore, ea dignissimos aperiam commodi necessitatibus doloremque?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nam, vero recusandae, minus repudiandae quo vel. Laudantium suscipit eum quod voluptatum fugit, quaerat, rerum labore porro, facere possimus enim quos.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptatibus dolorem dolor labore ut, iure iusto ratione inventore optio ab libero. Repellendus nostrum illo vel accusamus recusandae, omnis velit sed?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam, natus sed, nisi ratione, delectus sequi ullam consequuntur neque quas veritatis fugit dolore inventore, ea dignissimos aperiam commodi necessitatibus doloremque?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nam, vero recusandae, minus repudiandae quo vel. Laudantium suscipit eum quod voluptatum fugit, quaerat, rerum labore porro, facere possimus enim quos.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptatibus dolorem dolor labore ut, iure iusto ratione inventore optio ab libero. Repellendus nostrum illo vel accusamus recusandae, omnis velit sed?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam, natus sed, nisi ratione, delectus sequi ullam consequuntur neque quas veritatis fugit dolore inventore, ea dignissimos aperiam commodi necessitatibus doloremque?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nam, vero recusandae, minus repudiandae quo vel. Laudantium suscipit eum quod voluptatum fugit, quaerat, rerum labore porro, facere possimus enim quos.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptatibus dolorem dolor labore ut, iure iusto ratione inventore optio ab libero. Repellendus nostrum illo vel accusamus recusandae, omnis velit sed?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam, natus sed, nisi ratione, delectus sequi ullam consequuntur neque quas veritatis fugit dolore inventore, ea dignissimos aperiam commodi necessitatibus doloremque?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nam, vero recusandae, minus repudiandae quo vel. Laudantium suscipit eum quod voluptatum fugit, quaerat, rerum labore porro, facere possimus enim quos.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptatibus dolorem dolor labore ut, iure iusto ratione inventore optio ab libero. Repellendus nostrum illo vel accusamus recusandae, omnis velit sed?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Culpa ipsam, natus sed, nisi ratione, delectus sequi ullam consequuntur neque quas veritatis fugit dolore inventore, ea dignissimos aperiam commodi necessitatibus doloremque?
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sint nam, vero recusandae, minus repudiandae quo vel. Laudantium suscipit eum quod voluptatum fugit, quaerat, rerum labore porro, facere possimus enim quos.
 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Eius voluptatibus dolorem dolor labore ut, iure iusto ratione inventore optio ab libero. Repellendus nostrum illo vel accusamus recusandae, omnis velit sed?
</main>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you are asking for, but based on how a navbar should function. I would do the following.

I would change the css in your .header-wrapper to the following.

```
.header-wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
    z-index: 10;
    position: relative;
    min-height: 80px;
}
```

Comment: Another food for thought, I would recommend you look into frameworks such as bootstrap 3 & 4. This should help you tremendously in your coding journey. https://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: If this answer helped you, please mark as a solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In both images there is a top, left and right distance from the window border. The actual position isn't really different in these images, only in the second one the content becomes visible around the navbar.

If you intend your navbar to really span the full width and start at the top, you'll probably have to add this to your CSS to avoid the default margins:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

If you still want the navbar to keep some distance to the top, but without anything being visible above it when scrolled, you can put the navbar into a container DIV that has a white background and some padding.